# Cannot get new app scoped user id with Facebook api 2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

Recently I updated my old v1.0 Facebook web  app to api v2.0,
I changed the SDK call according to the upgrade guide of Facebook, then I created a new facebook account to login to my app, when I called me/ it still returned the global user id instead of the new app scoped id.

Anything I'm doing wrong?
I also tried it on the iPhone sdk and it did return the new app scoped id.

Thanks a lot.

Below is how I called the api:

```
<script>

function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // Logged into your app and Facebook.
        testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into this app.';
    } else {

        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into Facebook.';
    }
}

function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'MY_APPID',
        cookie: true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
        // the session
        xfbml: true,  // parse social plugins on this page
        version: 'v2.0' // use version 2.0
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });

};

(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
} (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function testAPI() {
    FB.api('v2.0/me', function (response) {
        log(response);
    });
}
```

Comment: You should always get the same identifier for a user who authorises your app - after updating your auth and API calls to v2.0, the older users' ids should not change, only new users should get 'app scoped' IDs

Comment: @Igy I know this. That's why I created a completely new account who had never authorised the app before I changed the api call. But it still returned the global id.

Answer (score 0):

Users who already authorized your App with v1.0 will keep the same ID. Else it would be impossible to match existing users.

If you still get the global ID with another account who never authorized the App before, your App is most likely not updated to v2.0.

Comment: I've edited the post with my code, please tell me if I'm calling it correctly. Thanks!

Comment: looks correct to me, although i don´t think you need the version tag in the api calls if you init the js sdk with v2.0. if you still get global ids for new users, i´d file a bug.